# Structural Equation for Frenet Frame of a Curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that the structural equation for the Frenet frame of a curve in $R^3$ can be put into the form

$t'(s) = w(s) \times t(s),$ $n'(s) = w(s) \times n(s),$ $b'(s) = w(s) \times b(s)$

for a certain vector $w(s)$. Find this vector.

I am unsure of how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: I edited your post, replacing your $x$ operator with the more coventional $\times$.  Remember, "\$a\$ \$x\$ \$b\$" produces $a$ $x$ $b$, whereas "\$a \times b\$" yields $a \times b$.  Nice problem, ***+1!!!*** Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $T(s)$, $N(s)$ and $B(s)$ satisfy the Frenet-Serret equations

$\dot T(s) = \kappa N(s), \tag 1$

$\dot N(s) = -\kappa T(s) + \tau B(s), \tag 2$

and

$\dot B(s) = -\tau N(s), \tag 3$

we seek a vector $W(s)$ such that

$\dot T(s) = W(s) \times T(s), \tag 4$

$\dot N(s) = W(s) \times N(s), \tag 5$

and

$\dot B(s) = W(s) \times B(s) \tag 6$

hold; set

$W(s) = \alpha T(s) + \beta N(s) + \gamma B(s); \tag 7$

then since $T(s) \times T(s) = 0$,

$\kappa N(s) = \dot T(s)  = W(s) \times T(s) = \beta N(s) \times T(s) + \gamma B(s) \times T(s) = -\beta B(s) + \gamma N(s), \tag 8$

where we have used the defining equation for $B(s)$,

$B(s) = T(s) \times N(s) = -N(s) \times T(s) \Longleftrightarrow B(s) \times T(s) = N(s) = -T(s) \times B(s); \tag 9$

from (8),

$\beta = 0, \; \gamma = \kappa; \tag{10}$

then

$W(s) = \alpha T(s) + \kappa B(s); \tag{11}$

next, using $B(s) \times B(s) = 0$ and (9),

$-\tau N(s) = \dot B(s) = W(s) \times B(s) = \alpha T(s) \times B(s) = -\alpha N(s), \tag{13}$

and so it follows that

$\alpha = \tau, \tag{14}$

whence

$W(s) = \tau T(s) + \kappa B(s); \tag{15}$

it is clear from what we have done that

$\dot T(s) = W(s) \times T(s), \tag{16}$

and

$\dot B(s) = W(s) \times B(s); \tag{17}$

we also see that, using $T(s) = -B(s) \times N(s)$,

$\dot N(s) = -\kappa T(s) + \tau B(s)$
$= \kappa B(s) \times N(s)   + \tau T(s) \times N(s) = (\kappa B(s) + \tau T(s)) \times N(s) = W(s) \times N(s). \tag{18}$

***Question:*** How does $W(s)$ evolve?  Does it satisfy a nice, intuitively clear equation?